# Custom php+ajax form in Wordpress not working

Tags: php, ajax, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a custom contact form for Worpress. I cannot use plugins so I am creating a new template page with the form in it, using php and ajax.

When I try to submit though, nothing happens. It doesn't clear all the fields, as intended, nor does it display a success message, and no email is sent.

I have little knowledge on php and ajax. I asked someone to take care of those parts. But he also can't figure out what's going on. He says the form works on his server. He is not testing the code on Wordpress like I am though.

Any help?

I have two files in the Wordpress theme folder:

index.php:

```js
        function _(el){
            return document.getElementById(el);
        }
        function submitForm() {
         var f1 = f2 = f3 = f4= f5 =f6=0;
        // get input field values    
        var form_name= _('form_name').value;
        var form_email= _('form_email').value;
        var form_phone= _('form_phone').value;
        var form_message= _('form_message').value;
        var form_agree= _('form_agree').checked;
        var e = document.getElementById("inputState");
        var inputState = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        
        //check if any fields are empty or not
        if(form_name == ""){
            _('form_name_error').innerHTML="Please enter your name";
            
        }
        else{
            _('form_name_error').innerHTML="";
            f1=1;
            
        }
        if(form_email == ""){
            _('form_email_error').innerHTML="Please enter your email";
        }
        else{
            _('form_email_error').innerHTML="";
            f2=1;
        }
        if(form_phone == ""){
            _('form_phone_error').innerHTML="Please enter your phone";
        }
        else{
            _('form_phone_error').innerHTML="";
            f3=1;
        }
        if(form_message == ""){
            _('form_message_error').innerHTML="Please enter your message";
        }
        else{
            _('form_message_error').innerHTML="";
            f4=1;
        }
        if(form_agree == false){
            _('form_agree_error').innerHTML="Please agree to the terms and conditions";
        }
        else{
            _('form_agree_error').innerHTML="";
            f5=1;
        }
        if(inputState == ""){
            _('inputState_error').innerHTML="Please select a department";
        }
        else{
            _('inputState_error').innerHTML="";
            f6=1;
        }
             
        if(f1==1 && f2==1 && f3==1 && f4==1 && f5==1 && f6==1){     
            // prepare formdata and assemble data into array for ajax request
            var fd = new FormData(); 
            fd.append("form_name",form_name);
            fd.append("form_email",form_email);
            fd.append("form_phone",form_phone);
            fd.append("form_message",form_message);
            fd.append("form_agree",form_agree);
            fd.append("inputState",inputState);
            
            // if ok, give ajax request to formMalier.php file and recieve JSON response
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     var form_data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                     //if sucessfully submitted empty the fields and display success message in form_answer div
                     if(form_data.formstatus == "success"){
                         _('form_answer').innerHTML="Success!";
                            _('form_name').value="";
                            _('form_email').value="";
                            _('form_phone').value="";
                            _('form_message').value="";
                            _('form_agree').checked="";
                         
                     }
                     //display failed message in form_answer div
                     else if(form_data.formstatus == "failed"){
                         _('form_answer').innerHTML="Failed";
                     }
                     else{
                         _('form_answer').innerHTML="Unexpected Error!"; 
                     }
                     
                }
            };
            //post request to php file
            xhttp.open("POST", "formMailer.php", true);
            xhttp.send(fd);
            
        }
        }
```

```html
    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Contact Form</h1>
            <div id="form_answer"></div><!--for error message -->
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
                    <div id ="form_name_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" id="form_phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your phone">
                    <div id ="form_phone_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" id="form_email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email">
                    <div id ="form_email_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="department">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Department</option>
                        <option>HR</option>
                        <option>CTO</option>
                        <option>PRW</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id ="inputState_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" id="form_message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    <div id ="form_message_error"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="form_agree" name="check"> I agree with the terms and conditions.
                        <div id ="form_agree_error"></div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="send message" onclick="submitForm()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And formMailer.php:

```
<?php
// checks if POST request By AJAX method
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // security function for invalid characters and prevents sql injection characters
    function test_input($data){
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data=stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // get purified data variables
    $form_name = test_input($_POST['form_name']);
    $form_email = test_input($_POST['form_email']);
    $form_phone = test_input($_POST['form_phone']);
    $form_message = test_input($_POST['form_message']);
    $inputState = test_input($_POST['inputState']);


    // send mail with subject as data
    $to = " <email@domain.com> ";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = $form_name.$form_email.$form_phone.$form_message.$form_agree.$inputState;
    $headers = "From: <email@domain.com>";

    //if mail success  
    if(wp_mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
        $formstatuscode = "success";
    }
    else{
         $formstatuscode = "failed";
    }

    // make formstatus array and ecode in json format and send response
    $formresponse = ["formstatus" => $formstatuscode];

    echo json_encode($formresponse);

}
```

?>

**EDIT:**

Going through the Network tab in the Developer Tools, it seems like the formMailer.php is not found. It Gives the error "failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)".

I was working with inline css. I created a separate file with all the styles, to test if it is just a matter of Wordpress not being able to link to external documents. After adding the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` to the index.php head, it gives the same 404 error.

I tried using both relative and absolute references. It still cannot find any external file.

Comment: This code is horrible. What have you tried? Does the AJAX request come through in the Network tab in devtools?

Comment: This is what it displays in the Network tab:
https://i.imgur.com/FCYTGnD.png

As I stated, I don't understand much about php, or ajax. I asked someone to take care of that part. I don't know what he tried.He just said that he cannot figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: formMailer.php gives a 404 error. Do you know what that means?